# Creating a view for a many to many relation ship in .net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, many-to-many

I'm creating a MediaLibrary in MVC.
I have a "MediaType" Model and a "Support" model.
Each MediaType (Film, Game, Music) can have n Support (CD, DVD, BluRay,...).

I created the models and added the relations (hasmany, withmany,...), the controller and views for Support (no problem here), but I don't now how to manage the controller and view for the MediaType, to be able to add multiple Supports and to validate them with the model.

The MediaType model :

```
[Bind(Exclude = "MediaTypeId")]
public class MediaType
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int MediaTypeId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Media type")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    // Disponible supports
    public virtual ICollection<Support> Supports { get; set; }
}
```

The Support model

```
[Bind(Exclude = "SupportId")]
public class Support
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int SupportId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Support name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    // MediaTypes using this support (not used in the view now)
    public virtual ICollection<MediaType> MediaTypes { get; set; }
}
```

The Create action from the MediaType controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["SupportsList"] = new SelectList(db.Supports.ToList(), "SupportId", "name");
        return View();
    } 
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MediaType mediatype)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.MediaTypes.Add(mediatype);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        ViewData["SupportsList"] = new SelectList(db.Supports.ToList(), "SupportId", "name");
        return View(mediatype);
```

The Create view for the Create action of the MediaType controller (the part for the Supports)

```
<div class="editor-field" id="supportList">
        @Html.DropDownList("Supports", (SelectList)ViewData["SupportsList"])
        <a href="#" id="addSupport">Ajouter</a>&nbsp;<span id="addSupportError" class="error"></span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#addSupport').click(function () {
                if ($('input[name="SupportsIds[]"][value="' + $('#Supports').val() + '"]').length < 1) {
                    $('#supportList').append('<div>' + $('#Supports option:selected').text() + '<input type="hidden" name="SupportsIds[]" value="' + $('#Supports').val() + '" /></div>');
                    $('span#addSupportError').text('');
                } else {
                    $('span#addSupportError').text('The support has already been added');
                }
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

I actually did a weird script in jQuery to add Supports to the MediaType, there is a dropdown list with all supports in db, when you click add, it adds a label with the name and a hidden field with the id of the support (the hiddens fields names are "SupportIds[]" so it should return a List of support ids, no ?)

Did someone already coded something like this (many-to-many,...) ?